# Simple TextToColumns with FeildInfo not working

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the TextToColumns to take a Delimited field formatted as

MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM
(excel just views this as text, not a date- it is delimited by a space)

to just

DD/MM/YYYY

I want to do this for the entire second column of my spreadsheet, starting at the 2nd cell

So far, I set my second column as the range (I set B2 to B2000 because I don't want to effect B1). I specified that the data is delimited with a space, that the first column needs to be formatted as DataType 6 and the second needs to be skipped.

```
'define and set range

Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Range("B2:B2000")

'use Text To Columns

rng.TextToColumns Destination:=rng, DataType:=xIDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote, 
Space:=True, 
FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 6), Array(2, 9))
```

When I run the code nothing happens at all. No errors, but no results either

Comment: When I use the manual "Text to Columns Wizard," it works when I select "space" as the delimiter. I do not think that excel sees the dates as true dates - just a text

Comment: Assuming `B2:B2000` contains `Date` values (as *seems* to be the case), `=DATE(YEAR(B2),MONTH(B2),DAY(B2))` for the date part, and `=TIME(HOUR(B2),MINUTE(B2),SECOND(B2))` for the time part. No need for any VBA or wizard for this; how the date is shown should be a simple `NumberFormat` ...don't treat dates as text if you can help it.

Comment: I would like to write this as a VBA so that it can be the first part of a larger script. The excel does not see the values as Date values, it just sees them as text, hence why I need to use the text to columns option. Simply reformatting the cells to a date format does nothing. I am working with a spreadsheet from a third party, so I have no say over how the dates are treated when I receive them- this is why I'm hoping to write code that automatically takes care of it for me

Comment: You have a typo:  should be:  `DataType:=xlDelimited`  IF you had `Option Explicit`, you would have been alerted to that.  I don't understand why MS makes NOT requiring variable declaration the default. Select `Tools/Options/Editor` and check `Require Variable Declaration`.  This will place `Option Explicit` at the start of any new module.  To correct **this** module, enter it manually at the beginning.

Comment: @ScottCraner TTC works here with true dates, and splits dates from times using the space delimiter, whether via VBA or on the worksheet.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld interesting, learned something new.  Never used TTC for something like this.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've run into  it before when importing CSV using the legacy import wizard, and being frustrated about having to recombine the date/time. Power Query is more flexible in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your code:

You have:  `DataType:=xIDelimited`

Should be:  `DataType:=xlDelimited`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, v As String, d As Date

    Set rng = Range("B2:B2000")
    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Text
        If InStr(1, v, "/") > 0 Then
            arr = Split(v, " ")
            brr = Split(arr(0), "/")
            d = DateSerial(brr(2), brr(0), brr(1))
            r.Clear
            r.Value = d
            r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

before:

[image]

and after:

[image]